# ORDER BY FIELD() and duplicate data

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following query.

```
SELECT stringdata FROM table ORDER BY FIELDS( stringdata, 'tg','nk','mg','pl') asc;
```

For some reason I'm getting the results at the very bottom. How can I get the query to put the results starting from 'tg' at row 1 rather than the last row in the results?

Not only that but there's more than one 'tg' in the data, I'd like it to sort it in this expected output:

```
stringdata
__________
   'tg'
   'tg'
   'tg'
   'nk'
   'nk'
   'mg'
   'mg'
   'mg'
   'pl'
```

So far using `ORDER BY Fields()` is only sorting one instance of the data rather than all.

Using `desc` instead of `asc` in the query works as expected. I get `'pl'` on the first row, then `'mg'`, `'nk'`,  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `FIELD` clause in `ORDER BY` works something like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(field, high_priority, second_high,
               ,....., low_priority);
```

So in your query, the sorting took place as you mentioned and when you gave the `ASC` it printed from the lowest_priority. So, for your case, if you want `tg` at the top, you can either reorder the priority in the `FIELDS` or as you have already tried use `desc`

Comment: The problem is that if I don't define ALL of the possible field(stringdata, 'tg', 'etc') ASC gets pushed all the way to the bottom. While the ones I didn't define come as the first results.

Comment: @Tek: Thats because the ones you dont define are considered to have lowest priority, so when ordering `ASC` they tend to come first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want first rows with `'tg'`, then rows with .... then with `'pl'` and then all the rest sorted (`ASC` or `DESC`) use this:

```
SELECT stringdata 
FROM table 
ORDER BY FIELD( stringdata, 'pl','mg', 'nk', 'tg') DESC
       , stringdata ASC        --- or DESC
```